# TinyOS interrupts handling

Tags: radio, msp430

I'm working on a sensor project which uses TelosB based on [CC2420](http://www.ti.com/product/CC2420) and [MSP430F1611](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430F1611) running TinyOS.

The aim of the project is to measure the distance between two devices. I was thinking to measure the time needed by a signal to go from a device to another and return. To have some precise values I need to find the exact moment when the transmission starts and the reciving starts. I think these can be made by triggering an interruption on the SFD pin(which changes it's state at the start of transmission,end of transmission, start of recieving and end of recieving).

I use the component component(HplCC2420InterruptsC) with CaptureSFD interface which returns the timp of the SFD change but the precision is only in 32Khz timer:

```
async event void CaptureSFD.captured(uint16_t time)
```

this is the event triggered.

I need microseconds, that's why I search for a way to trigger an interrupt, so I can save a time value in microseconds (the event from the above interface is asyncronously triggered so the time difference is too big).

So how do I trigger in this system (TINYOS) a syncronous interruption whenever the SFD pin changes value(1 or 0)?

Comment: I find it extremely difficult to comprehend what you're writing about. Please make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: Hi. I closed the question, to give you the time to improve it a bit before getting misleading answers. Could you please reword it to make clear what you are trying to achieve and what problem you are facing?

Comment: I've rewritten it. I'm sorry for the missunderstandings.

Comment: This looks a bit better, but do try to make it even better. Link to relevant datasheets and tell us a bit more about processing at the devices. I have a feeling that waiting to transmit will take more than time it takes for wave to go through the air. Also few more empty lines would make question a bit easier to read.

Comment: I've edited again. I don't look for an algorithm, just for a few lines of code that are the implementation of the interruption. For a person that is familiar with TinyOS it will sond ok. Thank you

Comment: You would put the address to your interrupt service routine at 0FFE8h,
see this [http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f1611.pdf][1]

Comment: That sounds promising, but I can't find a method to implement it using this API: http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.x/doc/nesdoc/telosb/index.html. What do you think about Andy's answear? Is it plausible? In that case it is usless to set this up as I won't get any result. Especially that I don't have a nanosecond precision...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a radio link and you transmit A to B, then B to A and you want to measure the "send and return" time. If I've got this wrong please do ignore my ramblings.

If the two devices are say 30m apart, a radio wave will take about 100nsec to cover that distance. Your transmission (including preamble and a few bytes - lets say 25 bits in total) will be about 100usec long at 250kbpersec.

The "circuit" that initially receives the 1st transmission won't be "synchronized" with the transmission and will therefore not be ready for it and it will (eventually) align itself with the transmitted preamble in several usec +/- several more usec.

From here, it should be obvious to you that it won't work with any decent resolution. Maybe if you want to tell if the distance between the units is in miles it might just about work.

Small print - I haven't looked at how good zigbees are on data transmission and reception so please don't crit if I have misrepresented it by assuming it needs some form of preamble.

EDIT - this edit considers the possibility that if you average thousands of transmissions to and from the target device you might be able to construct a "number" that just might have better resolution that a few micro seconds.